# Неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
#ifndef GEOMETRY_H
#define GEOMETRY_H

//Пространство имен для геометрии
namespace g{
    //Класс двумерной точки
    //Для задания начала и конца отрезков
    class point{
    private:
        double _x, _y;
    public:
        point(double xn, double yn)
            : _x(xn), _y(yn) {}
        double x() {return _x;}
        double y() {return _y;}
    };

    //Класс двумерного вектора
    //Для определения вектора, соответствующего отрезку
    class vector{
    private:
        double _x, _y;
    public:
        vector(double xn, double yn)
            : _x(xn), _y(yn) {}
        double x() {return _x;}
        double y() {return _y;}
    };

    //Класс отрезка на плоскости
    struct segment{
    private:
        point _begin, _end;
        vector _v;  //Координаты вектора
    public:
        segment(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
            : _begin(x1, y1), _end(x2, y2), _v(x2 - x1, y2 - y1){}
        point begin(){return _begin;}
        point end()  {return _end;}
        vector v()   {return _v;}
    };

    double vector_product(vector a, vector b);
```

Файл geometry.cpp:

```
#include "geometry.h"

double vector_product(g::vector a, g::vector b){
    return a.x() * b.y() - a.y() * b.x();
}
```

Файл main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "geometry.h"

int main(){
    g::segment a(2, 4, 3, 2);
    g::segment b(2, 2, 6, 6);

    g::point p(1.3, 2);
    std::cout << p.x() << " " << p.y() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.v().x() << " " << a.v().y() << std::endl;
    std::cout << g::vector_product(a.v(), b.v()) << std::endl;

    int pause;
    std::cin >> pause;
}
```

При компиляции возникает ошибка: неразрешенный внешний символ ""double __cdecl g::vector_product(class g::vector,class g::vector)" (?vector_product@g@@YANVvector@1@0@Z)".

Что здесь не так и как исправить?

}

## endif

Comment: попробуйте в cpp свою реализацию тоже в namespace заключить.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский: Опубликуете как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит так, как будто бы вы забыли поместить определение функции в пространство имен `g`

Напишите

Файл geometry.cpp:

```
#include "geometry.h"

namespace g
{
double vector_product(vector a, vector b){
    return a.x() * b.y() - a.y() * b.x();
}
}
```

Или без использования пространства имен можно записать

```
#include "geometry.h"

double g::vector_product(g::vector a, g::vector b){
    return a.x() * b.y() - a.y() * b.x();
}
```